# Finding least and highest month revenue

Tags: sql, oracle

I was having a problem for organizing a table where shows me
 the month with the highest revenue and the lowest order by revenue

all the information is in the same table (Ordertable)

So I have orderdate and orderfinalprice.

```
select orderdate as MonthsSales, Highestrevenue, Lowestrevenue
from 
(select months
, max (orderfinalprice) as Highestrevenue, min (orderfinalprice) as Lowestrevenue
From hologicOrder_T)
order by monthsales;
```

Comment: Does the table contains one record per month? Please show us sample data and expected results.

Comment: To create meaningful questions check this link we are Glad to help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

What's missing is the grouping by `month` based on `orderdate`.

```
select orderdate as MonthsSales, Highestrevenue, Lowestrevenue 
from 
    (select to_char(orderdate, 'Month') orderdate, max(orderfinalprice) as Highestrevenue
        , min (orderfinalprice) as Lowestrevenue 
    from hologicOrder_T
    group by to_char(orderdate, 'Month')) 
order by monthsales;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem, you want two months data, one with highest revenue and one with lowest revenue.

You can get it by following:

```
Select max(case when minrn = 1 then month_ end) lowestrevenue_month, 
       max(case when minrn = 1 then totalrevenue end) lowestrevenue,
       max(case when maxrn = 1 then month_ end) highestrevenue_month, 
       max(case when maxrn = 1 then totalrevenue end) highestrevenue
From
(Select trunc(orderdate, 'month') month_,
       Sum(orderfinalprice) as totalrevenue,
       Row_nuumber() over (partition by trunc(orderdate, 'month') order by Sum(orderfinalprice)) as minrn,
       Row_nuumber() over (partition by trunc(orderdate, 'month') order by Sum(orderfinalprice) desc) as maxrn
  From hologicOrder_T
Group by trunc(orderdate, 'month') )
Where 1 in (minrn, maxrn);
```

You should not use `to_char(orderdate, 'Month')` because it will be same for the month regardless of its year.

In output, `highestrevenue_month` and  `lowestrevenue_month` will be first date of the month, you can format it accordingly using `to_char`.

Cheers!!